# Split string on spaces in Java, except if between quotes (i.e. treat \"hello world\" as one token)

Tags: java

How do I split a `String` based on space but take quoted substrings as one word?

Example:

```
Location "Welcome  to india" Bangalore Channai "IT city"  Mysore
```

it should be stored in `ArrayList` as

```
Location
Welcome to india
Bangalore
Channai
IT city
Mysore
```

Comment: IMO even though the dupe-linked question is older, this answer by aioobe is the better of the two as it has the superior regex recipe for extracting matches.

Comment: In my case I had a string that includes key="value" . Check this out:
  ```String perfLogString = "2022-11-10 08:35:00,470     PLV=REQ CIP=902.68.5.11 CMID=canonaustr CMN=\"Yanon Australia Pty Ltd\""; ```
    // and this came to my rescue :

    ```String[] str1= perfLogString.split("\\s(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\\s*");System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str1));```

This regex matches spaces ONLY if it is followed by even number of double quotes. 
On split I get : [2022-11-10, 08:35:00,470, PLV=REQ, CIP=902.68.5.11, CMID=canonaustr, CMN="Yanon Australia Pty Ltd"]

Answer (score 148):

Here's how:

```
String str = "Location \"Welcome  to india\" Bangalore " +
             "Channai \"IT city\"  Mysore";

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^\"]\\S*|\".+?\")\\s*").matcher(str);
while (m.find())
    list.add(m.group(1)); // Add .replace("\"", "") to remove surrounding quotes.


System.out.println(list);
```

**Output:**

```
[Location, "Welcome  to india", Bangalore, Channai, "IT city", Mysore]
```

The regular expression simply says

- `[^"]`     - token starting with something other than `"`
- `\S*`       - followed by zero or more non-space characters
- ...or...
- `".+?"`   - a `"`-symbol followed by whatever, until another `"`.

Comment: Location, "Welcome to india", Bangalore, Channai, "IT city", Mysore  it is one String i'm entering in jsp form, after submitting  it should be split as it is i mentioned in question

Comment: double quote should not be there

Comment: Ah, change `m.group(1)` to `m.group(1).replace("\"", "")`.

Comment: `[^\"]` should be replaced with `[^\"\\s]` in case if you don't need spaces in the beginning of the string as part of the first element.

Comment: @Tema, that concern is orthogonal to the `"..."` grouping (and arguably application specific). I would strongly advice using `String.trim` when processing the string instead of making an already complex regexp even more complicated.

Comment: If you reverse the alternation, you don't need to to make the check for "not starting with a quote" because the regex engine will prefer the thing on the left of the alternation first. [Here's an example](https://regex101.com/r/dA9hJ0/1)

Comment: Any reason for ".+?" and not just ".*" ?

Comment: sadly it fails on inner quotes: 'exec -s something -e "lala \"lo lo\" lulu" -f $file'. it also wont work with single quotes. how to command line interpreters  like bash parse such strings?

Comment: I got fail when string contain colon (:), example: "age:30 name:\"john doe\"". Output [age:30] [name:"john] [doe"]

Comment: @windupurnomo, that has nothing to do with the `:` though.

Comment: @aioobe - How do I handle this case ?: ```str = "First Second=\"This  is Second\" Third=3  \"this  is Four\""``` . I want is [First] [Second="This  is Second"]  [Third=3] [this  is Four]