# Split string into words with whitespace unless in between a pair of double quotation marks

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to split this string:

> get "something" from "any site"

to array.
I've done that:

```
var array = $(this).val().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(" ");
```

But I don't want to split words in quotation marks ("").

whether it can be done in a simple way?

Comment: take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804335/split-string-on-spaces-except-if-between-quotes-i-e-treat-hello-world-as). might help

Comment: @dystroy: Of course it does preserve them! The answer also includes a modification on how to remove them

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A solution :

```
var str = 'get "something" from "any site"';
var tokens = [].concat.apply([], str.split('"').map(function(v,i){
   return i%2 ? v : v.split(' ')
})).filter(Boolean);
```

Result :

```
["get", "something", "from", "any site"]
```

It's probably possible to do simpler. The idea here is to split using `"` and then split by the space the odd results of the first splitting.

If you want to keep the quotes, you may use

```
var tokens = [].concat.apply([], str.split('"').map(function(v,i){
     return i%2 ? '"'+v+'"' : v.split(' ')
})).filter(Boolean);
```

Result :

```
['get', '"something"', 'from', '"any site"']
```

Comment: Sorry about editing it, it looked like it was wrong, but in fact it's good :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Because he needs a `concatMap`…

Comment: @Bergi We do have `concatMap` in JS ?

Comment: @dystroy: No, precisely not - else you would've used it :-)

Answer (score 2):

#### Here is how to do it with a regular expression:

[`("\[a-zA-Z\s\]+"|\[a-zA-Z\]+)/g`](http://regex101.com/r/bQ7gF6) : Explanation of the expression is at the link.

#### Here is how you would use it:

```
var re = /([a-zA-Z]+)|("[a-zA-Z\s]+"?)\s?/g; 
var str = 'get "something" from "any site"';
var match = re.exec(str);
alert(match[1]); \\ this will give you the first matched group
                   \\ in this case it would be the word "get"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BqEBn/1/))

```
function extract(input) {
    var elements = input.split(/([^\"]\S*|\".+?\")\s*/),
        matches = [];
    for(index in elements) {
        if(elements[index].length > 0) {
            if(elements[index].charAt(0) === '"') {
                matches.push(elements[index].substring(1, elements[index].length-1));
            } else {
                matches.push(elements[index]);
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
alert(extract('get "something" from "any site"'))
```

Answer (score -2):

A very simple answer to this :

```
'get "something" from "any site"'.split(/"/);
```

["get ", "something", " from ", "any site", ""]

:)

Comment: Try it with `var str = 'get "something" from "any site" and shoud work.';`

Comment: Wait for a second and someone bangs you with answers! So fast is everyone at stackoverflow!

However @ dystroy my answer uses least keystrokes ;)