# Javascript - performance issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, performance

everybody,

I'm having performance problems with my code. An input string looks like this:

> 'intput = valueA valueB valueC "valueD 13" valueF... valueZ'

The goal is to assign dedicated variables to each value.  Currently my code looks like this:

```
var myArray = intput.split(/ +(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);
outputOne = myArray[1];
outputTwo = myArray[2];
outputThree = myArray[3];
outputFour = myArray[4];
...
outputX = myArray[30];
```

It seems, however, that my code is not performant enough. I'd like to process about 500 input strings per second, but I'm currently only able to process about 120.

Even a .exec doesn't change that much. I have tried the following regex:

```
var myArraytwo =/(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\".*?\")\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s/.exec(bufferString)
```

Is there a faster way to assign the above string to dedicated variables?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261635/javascript-split-string-by-space-but-ignore-space-in-quotes-notice-not-to-spli? `/ +(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/` is a very slow pattern. `/[^\s"]+|"[^"]*"/g` should be faster

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18703767/3832970.