# Count and split string with space except if between quotes in NSIS

Tags: string, split, nsis

My question is like [Split string on spaces in Java, except if between quotes (i.e. treat \"hello world\" as one token)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804335) but in NSIS way.
Hopefully without any external plugins.

> How do I split a String based on space but take quoted substrings as
>   one word?
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Location "Welcome to india" Bangalore Channai "IT city"  Mysore
> ```
>
> it should be stored in ArrayList as
>
> ```
> Location
> Welcome to india
> Bangalore
> Channai
> IT city
> Mysore
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no array support without plugins so I left out the array part.

Any string operation can be performed with the 3 basic string functions in NSIS (StrLen, StrCpy and StrCmp):

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Function SplitArg
Exch $0 ; str
Push $1 ; inQ
Push $3 ; idx
Push $4 ; tmp
StrCpy $1 0
StrCpy $3 0
loop:
    StrCpy $4 $0 1 $3
    ${If} $4 == '"'
        ${If} $1 <> 0 
            StrCpy $0 $0 "" 1
            IntOp $3 $3 - 1
        ${EndIf}
        IntOp $1 $1 !
    ${EndIf}
    ${If} $4 == '' ; The end?
        StrCpy $1 0
        StrCpy $4 ' '
    ${EndIf} 
    ${If} $4 == ' '
    ${AndIf} $1 = 0
        StrCpy $4 $0 $3
        StrCpy $1 $4 "" -1
        ${IfThen} $1 == '"' ${|} StrCpy $4 $4 -1 ${|}
        killspace:
            IntOp $3 $3 + 1
            StrCpy $0 $0 "" $3
            StrCpy $1 $0 1
            StrCpy $3 0
            StrCmp $1 ' ' killspace
        Push $0 ; Remaining
        Exch 4
        Pop $0
        StrCmp $4 "" 0 moreleft
            Pop $4
            Pop $3
            Pop $1
            Return
        moreleft:
        Exch $4
        Exch 2
        Pop $1
        Pop $3
        Return
    ${EndIf}
    IntOp $3 $3 + 1
    Goto loop
FunctionEnd


Section
push 'Location "Welcome to india" Bangalore Channai "IT city"  Mysore'
loop:
    call SplitArg
    Pop $0
    StrCmp $0 "" done
    DetailPrint Item=|$0|
    goto loop
done:
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Yes it is working, thanks. But how can I make it work like ${StrTok} ?

Comment: If you want ${StrTok} why not just use it? I changed the code to return the string one by one...

Comment: Because I don't know how to handle quotation marks with ${StrTok}