# Java - Regular Expression for tokenzing a string based on white spaces not inside ""

Tags: java, regex, tokenize

I am working on a problem which requires me to tokenize a string on the basis of white spaces except those which occur inside quotation marks. For example for the string :

```
printf ( " the quick brown fox " ) ;
```

The tokens generated should be:

```
printf, (, ", the quick brown fox , ", ), ;
```

So far I came up with the following code but it does not seem to do what I intend it to.

```
String m = "printf ( " the quick brown fox " ) ;"

String [] tokens = m.split("([^\"])(\\w)*(\\s)(\\w)*([^\"])");
```

Any help would be really appreciated !

Comment: In your example: why should it split after `fox`? The whitespace after `fox` is inside ""!

Comment: It is indeed a duplication. I was about to propose a code that would have look very much like aioobe's answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804335/split-string-on-spaces-except-if-between-quotes-i-e-treat-hello-world-as.