# Splitting string by white space except for whitespace inside parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I need help on regex in split() method.

Here is what I have so far :

```
modelName.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Unfortunately, if I have a string such as this :

```
(Blue Yellow) Red Green
```

It would end up like this :

1. (Blue
2. Yellow)
3. Red
4. Green

How do I write a regex to get this result :

1. (Blue Yellow)
2. Red
3. Green

Comment: Just change [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7804472/1343161) to use parantheses instead of quotes.

Comment: Can parentheses nest in your input?

Comment: No, there is no nesting.

Comment: "([^\\(]\\S*|\\(.+?\\))\\s*" - ouch. But a single split is not sufficient, you need to compile it and use a matcher.

Comment: So I got this \s+(?=[^)]*([\(]|$)) and apparently it works.

Comment: @Renren29 Try to match instead of splitting `\([^)]+\)|\\S+`