# Java - Split string based on space and single quote but ignore two single quotes

Tags: java, regex

I want to split the string using space and single quote. But two single quotes should be ignored.

Input:

```
name eq 'a''b'
```

Output should be:

```
name

eq

a''b
```

I tried to use

```
[^\\s\"(?<!')'(?!')]+|\"[^\"]*\"|(?<!')'(?!')[^(?<!')'(?!')]*(?<!')'(?!')"
```

but it does not work.

Comment: You should be able to adapt the answer I've provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804335/split-string-on-spaces-except-if-between-quotes-i-e-treat-hello-world-as

Comment: Can there be spaces in the `'....'` strings?

Comment: Can you provide more context on your input string? Perhaps a more specific method is needed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
'(?:[^']|'')+'|[^ ]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Cc2FuHWYwTvsHZ3o)

---

Java example:

```java
String input = "foobar foo bar 'foobar' 'foo bar' 'foo''bar'";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(?:[^']|'')+'|[^ ]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group();
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/kwdYQw)

Answer (score 1):

Hi the actual regex is

```
"\\s|(?<!')'(?!')"
```

It produces output array as follows

```
[name, eq, , a''b]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without `regex` too.

```
String s = "name eq 'a''b'";
String[] split = new String[3];

Scanner in = new Scanner(s);

split[0] = in.next();
split[1] = in.next();

String temp = in.next();
split[2] = temp.substring(1,temp.length() - 1);

//test output
for(String x : split)
    System.out.println(x);
```

This will print:

```
name
eq
a''b
```

If you need a more generic solution you need to provide more details. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Your code is not optimal for all of cases. How about the input string which you're don't know in advance about? Eg: `lskh asd 'nkhj'g''hgfbgiuy' kjasfg'hb 'jhgb 'hjjh' gb'`

Comment: Which is why i am asking for more details. I guess you will agree that its pretty unclear if his input follows the same pattern  or if there are spaces allowed in between `' '` Or what to do if there is a `'` in between two chars. Which is why i asked for more details. But my answer covers the concept of split in `" "` first and stripping `'` after. Don't you think?

Comment: At my work, I need to write my code clear and useful for all of cases. Suppose, the most part of programmers in the world (except India ;) ), follows that rule. I think that your way is not useful for all of cases, and that is why downvoted. Sorry :) Wish you a clean code :)

Comment: Yes. If i knew all cases i would.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do:

```
String value = "name eq 'a''b'";
value = value.replaceAll(" '", " ").replaceAll("'$", "");
System.out.println(value);
String[] arr = value.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [**Lookaround**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Pattern

```
(?<!')'(?!')
```

Sample code:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("name eq 'a''b'".split("(?<!')'(?!')")));
```

output:

```
[name eq , a''b]
```

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
    '                        '\''
  )                        end of look-behind
  '                        '\''
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
    '                        '\''
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

---

To split based on space or single quote use

```
 *(?<!')[ '](?!') *
```

sample code:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("name eq 'a''b'".split(" *(?<!')[ '](?!') *")));
```

output:

```
[name, eq, a''b]
```

Comment: @sp00m to make sure just test it. It returns `[name eq , a, 'b]
`

Comment: IMHO you've got the best answer, except you must split on spaces and/or the single quote, not just single quote. Ie try this regex `" *(?<!')'(?!') *"`

Comment: @Bohemian yes added with few changes.

Comment: @user3218114 You'll split arguments like ``'foos'' bar'` at the interior space as well (not sure if OP wants that behaviour but I guess no).

Comment: @AlexR yes I agree there are lots of possibilities. Need clarification from OP first.