# Java split string with quoted values in middle of words

Tags: java, regex, string

I would really appreciate some help with Java code to split the following inputs:

```
word1 key="value with space" word3 -> [ "word1", "key=\"value with space\"", "word3" ]
word1 "word2 with space" word3 -> [ "word1", "word2 with space", "word3" ]
word1 word2 word3 -> [ "word1" , "word2", "word3" ]
```

The first sample input is the tough one.  The second word has quotes in the middle of the string not at the beginning.  I found several ways of dealing with the middle example such as described in [Split string on spaces in Java, except if between quotes (i.e. treat \"hello world\" as one token)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804335/split-string-on-spaces-in-java-except-if-between-quotes-i-e-treat-hello-wor)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using regex at all, you can do a simple iteration over the string:

```
public static String[] splitWords(String str) {
        List<String> array = new ArrayList<>(); 
        boolean inQuote = false; // Marker telling us if we are between quotes
        int previousStart = -1;  // The index of the beginning of the last word
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                if (previousStart != -1 && !inQuote) {
                    // end of word
                    array.add(str.substring(previousStart, i));
                    previousStart = -1;
                }
            } else {
                // possibly new word
                if (previousStart == -1) previousStart = i;
                // toggle state of quote
                if (c == '"')
                    inQuote = !inQuote;
            }
        }
        // Add last segment if there is one
        if (previousStart != -1) 
            array.add(str.substring(previousStart));
        return array.toArray(new String [array.size()]);
    }
```

This method has the advantage of being able to correctly identify quotes that are nowhere near spaces as many times as necessary. For example, the following is a single string:

```
a"b c"d"e f"g
```

Comment: This solves my problem!  See my code edits for a few typo fixes.  Thank you Mad Physicist!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a mix of regex and replace. Just find text surrounded by quotes first and replace with non-spaces. Then you can split the string based on spaces and replace back the key text.

```
    String s1 = "word1 key=\"value with space\" word3";

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"").matcher(s1);
    while (m.find())
        s1 = s1.replace(m.group(1), m.group(1).replace(" ", "||")); // replaces the spaces between quotes with ||

    for(String s : s1.split(" ")) {
        list.add(s.replace("||", " ")); // switch back the text to a space.
        System.out.println(s.replace("||", " ")); // just to see output
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The split can be done by using a look ahead in the regex:

```
String[] words = input.split(" +(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
```

---

Here's some test code:

```
String[] inputs = { "word1 key=\"value with space\" word3","word1 \"word2 with space\" word3", "word1 word2 word3"};
for (String input : inputs) {
    String[] words = input.split(" +(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
}
```

Ouput:

```
[word1, key="value with space", word3]
[word1, "word2 with space", word3]
[word1, word2, word3]
```