# How to split a string separated with multiple delimiters in java?

Tags: java

Assuming I had a text file sample.txt that has info like this:

```
John-Mike "male" "a computer scientist" 6 9
```

I want to read in this file into an array where

```
array[0] = John-Mike 
array[1] = male
array[2] = a computer scientist
array[3] = 6
array[4] = 9
```

i have tried

```
String[] tokens = file.nextLine().split(" ");
```

it gives me something like this instead

```
array[0] = John-Mike
array[1] = male
array[2] = a
array[3] = computer
array[4] = science
array[5] = student
.
.
.
```

but that splits all the whites paces including the ones in the apostrophe and stores them separately. How do I use split to manipulate this with scanner? I have searched all through the web for a good amount of time for a credible solution but I have found none yet. Any reference or info would be great

EDIT:

You cannot add anything to the text file just to make changes to the delimeter

Comment: So you want to split on white space except when there's a `"` until there's another `"`... just create a loop that does that or something similar... use your imagination ;)

Comment: If you don't agree that your question is duplicate post comment in which you will explain why it is not duplicate, [don't repost same question again](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36166924/1393766). Don't forget to add in your comment `@nickOfPerson` who closed your question as duplicate so he would be informed about your comment. This way (if you ware right) your question can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a regular expression in order to split it that way. Check out this post:
[Split string on spaces in Java, except if between quotes (i.e. treat \"hello world\" as one token)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804335/split-string-on-spaces-in-java-except-if-between-quotes-i-e-treat-hello-wor)

Comment: then I would need to change the way the file is by adding "\" but I don't want to add anything to the text file

Comment: I am trying to get the correct RE for you. meanwhile you can use the link.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about it is to extract them as groups with regex. For example:

```
String s = "John-Mike \"male\" \"a computer scientist\" 6 9";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w\\d-]+|\"[\\w\\d -]+\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
/* Result: 
John-Mike
"male"
"a computer scientist"
6
9
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to split string with `"` first and then, split it further if it contains white space and is not enclosed in quotes, e.g. something like this (not tested):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String s = "John-Mike \"male\" \"a computer scientist\" 6 9";
    String[] tokens = s.split("\"");
    List<String> newTokens = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String token : tokens){
        token = token.trim();
        if(token.isEmpty()){
            continue;
        }
        if(token.contains(" ") && !s.contains("\""+token+"\"")){
            //This means it is a separate string with spaces, in this case, split further
            for(String subToken : token.split(" ")){
                newTokens.add(subToken);
            }
        }else{
            newTokens.add(token);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newTokens);
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are not allowed to add or change  anything in the txt file. How would this be read?

Comment: You can read the file line by line and split it as described above.

Comment: you are adding \ to the txt file. reading it without adding "\" to split is what i am asking

Comment: I am not adding anything into file. I am just enclosing string with quotes and checking whether it exists into the original string.

Comment: `\\` is not being added to the file, it is to escape the quote in quotes in the string. If you were to print out the string it would not be there.

Comment: `String s = "John-Mike \"male\" \"a computer scientist\" 6 9";` should be `String s ="John-Mike "male" "a computer scientist" 6 9"` thats what I meant

Comment: That would not work if you try it. You have to escape the quotes within the quotes when you make a string.

Comment: That is just a java representation to escape the quotes. You can directly use the string returned by e.g. `br.readLine()` there.

Comment: @elle you are confusing what ``\`` is inside String. `"` is special character in Java which represents start and end of the string so you can't write something like `System.out.println("foo"bar");` because the middle `"` would be understood as end of string, which means only `"foo"` would be seen as proper string and `bar"` part would cause error. If you want to print something like `foo"bar` then you need to let Java see `"` as simple character, not control character. To so so we are escaping it by adding ``\`` before like `System.out.println("foo\"bar");`.

Comment: @elle In other words string literal `"foo\"bar"` represents string `foo"bar`. You don't need to worry about adding ``\`` to your text file because there each character is not treated as possible part of Java code, but as simple text so no escaping is needed.