# How to split string with space and quote both at the same time in scala?

Tags: java, regex, scala

I need to split string with quotes and white spaces in scala.

```
val str1="hello 'hi' 'how are' you"
str1.split(" ").foreach(println)
```

Expected o/p -

```
hello
'hi'
'how are'
you
```

words within the quote must be in output as it is!

Comment: Try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/7804472/7068014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7804472/7068014)

Comment: You're probably going to also want to deal with the case where the string in quotes can contain quotes, no? E.g., `'here's a string'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Guava](https://guava.dev/), by adding '"com.google.guava" % "guava" % "28.1-jre"' to build.sbt, you would call the scala equivalent to the Java code:

`String [] splitStringArray = Splitter.onPattern("['[:space:]]").split(inputString);`

Answer (score 2):

This works (at least for the specified input).

```
val str1="hello 'hi' 'how are' you"
"('[^']+'|[^\\s]+)".r.findAllIn(str1).foreach(println)
```

o/p:

```
hello
'hi'
'how are'
you
```

---

Or this simplification, as @Mike has kindly pointed out.

```
"'.+?'|\\S+".r.findAllIn(str1).foreach(println)
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `\S`. And triple quotes are usually the thing. Reluctant quantifiers are useful, too: `"""'.+?'|\S+"""`.

Comment: `\S` - **D'oh!** Yes, of course. _Reluctant quantifiers_ - For some reason that seldom comes to mind. I'll have to work on that. `"""` - When I get tired of double escapes I usually turn to the `raw` string interpolater.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to take escaped single quotes into account:

```
val str1="""hello 'hi' 'how are' you 'do\'ing?'"""
"""'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'|\S+""".r.findAllIn(str1).foreach(println)
```

Output

```
hello
'hi'
'how are'
you
'do\'ing?'
```

[Scala demo](https://ideone.com/jAwn3m) | [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0WIcdN/1)